# Copying of pixels when rotating a picture 90 degrees [Vec3d vs Vec3b]

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, segmentation-fault

Yes, I know there is a function for this, but this is a (very simple) function to learn OpenCV basics.

I checked the pseudo-code five times and am pretty sure this is no logical error.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2 || argv[1]=="") {
        printf("No image specified.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    Mat im, out;
    const string fn = argv[1];

    im = cv::imread(fn);
    out.create(im.cols, im.rows, CV_8UC3);

    //int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < out.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < out.cols; j++) {
            out.at<cv::Vec3d>(i, j) = im.at<cv::Vec3d>(im.rows-1-j, i);
            /*
             *if (tmp<1000) {tmp++;}
             *else {imwrite("/tmp/out.png", out); tmp=0;}
             */
        }
    }

    imwrite("/tmp/in.png", im);
    imwrite("/tmp/out.png", out);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Result]

I noticed that the width in the out picture is stretched exactly 3 times (1px→3px).
Plus, segmentation fault at the return.

**Update:**

Here’s the pseudo-code:

```
for(row=0; row<out.rows; row++) {
    for(col = 0; col<out.cols; col++) {
        out[row][col] = in[(in.rows-1)-col][row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the image as a grayscale image: `cv::imread(name, 0)`.

You should change that to: `cv::imread(name, 1)`, otherwise you cannot use `im.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)` (**notice the `Vec3b`**, instead of `Vec3d`, where `b` stands for unsigned char, `d` means double)

Comment: Huh, sorry, I changed that in my code and forgot to re-paste. So no, that’s not the problem with this (otherwise the pictures are greyscale, too).

Comment: Do you use `Vec3b` or `Vec3d`? You did not change that in your question.

Comment: You, sir, win all my Internets. For me this has always been a `3D vector`. Why stop templating here? I don’t get it. Must be a `C++` thing.

Comment: Oh, blasted. Don’t mind me, today is not my day. Of course this is templated, these are only typedef shorcuts…